# select item combobox from textblock wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, combobox

i want selected item from combo box when textbox not equal " "

i use this code

```
    if (txt_e1.Text != " ")
                {

               combobox1.SelectedIndex = combobox1.Items.IndexOf(txt_e1.Text);

                }
```

but dont show me anything

i get txt_e1 from another page and always equal with one of item in combobox

window loded code

```
   combobox1.ItemsSource = database.Mahs.ToList();
            combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = "MahName";
            combobox1.SelectedValuePath = "MahID";
```

i can not use

```
combobox1.text = txt_e1.Text;
```

because  in **combobox1 text change** i use this code

```
        if (datagrid_customer == null || combobox1 == null)
        { txt_f1.Text = "Not Matching"; }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < datagrid_customer.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString((datagrid_customer.SelectedCells[1].Column.GetCellContent(datagrid_customer.Items[i]) as TextBlock).Text) == combobox1.Text)
                    {
...
                     }
```

and i get error return null .

what should i do ?

Comment: First of all, I would suggest to learn `MVVM` and use `DataBinding` because this is the "correct" way of using WPF. Accessing GUI controls in CodeBehind should be avoided

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. If the textbox is not equel to an empty string then you want the value of the selected item in the combobox? Can you give some more context on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Where is the code where you set the `SelectedIndex`? Also, are you sure you mean `" "` (one space) and not `""` (empty string)? Consider using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)`.

Comment: @redcurry  yes because in xml code my text is " "(one space)

Comment: nobody can help